# i want to create composite foreign key but it gives my sql error 1005

Tags: mysql, composite

Table `complaint_record` with composite primary key

```
CREATE TABLE `complaint_record` (
  `complaint_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cat_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `store_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `complaint_data` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RCA` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `priority` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `assigned_to` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_submission` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`complaint_id`,`store_id`,`cat_id`),
  KEY `cat_id` (`cat_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `store_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `store_id_idx` (`store_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `cat_id` FOREIGN KEY (`cat_id`) REFERENCES `complaint_categories` (`cat_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `store_id` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `store_record` (`store_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

`Complaint_comment` table in it I want to create composite foreign key

```
CREATE TABLE `complaint_comment` (
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `complaint_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `store_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `cat_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `commented_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `comment` longtext NOT NULL,
  KEY `user_id_comment` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_id_comment` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

I am creating foreign key

```
ALTER TABLE `kabliwala_db`.`complaint_comment` ADD CONSTRAINT `complaint_key` FOREIGN KEY `complaint_key` (`complaint_id`, `store_id`, `cat_id`)
    REFERENCES `complaint_record` (`complaint_id`, `store_id`, `cat_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Comment: Please add some more information to the question. Where are you getting the error, what have you tried etc.

Comment: Have you tried understanding the meaning of that error code? Also, you might want to spend some more effort in formatting your SQL.

Comment: And please add a tag with the sql server you are using.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: I think I've found an answer for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812616/mysql-error-1005-cant-create-table-errno-150 (wasn't too hard)

Comment: error:   Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in
tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables
cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.

Comment: user714965:  i tried but it is not working.  through error  Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in complaint_comment table complaint_id is unsigned and int but in complaint_record table complaint_id is only int

i.e type of both the fields are different. so can't create an foreign key with different type.